# Looping selected region on AKPlayer

Tags: audiokit

I was experimenting with AKPlayer to implement on my multichannel audio playback project. What I learned with AKPlayer.play is that, I can set the playback region by assigning from:to: properties. But I was wondering if I can repeat/loop the assigned region only. Here's an example:

```
    func preparePlayer() {

    player.isLooping = true
    player.buffering = .always


    }

    func startPlayer() {

    let startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
    player.play(from: 0, to: 4, at: startTime, hostTime: nil)

    }
```

In this case, player can either loop forever (when player.isLooping is true), or play selected region (4 seconds) only once. Is there a way I could do both - Play a certain clip for 4 seconds but repeat that particular part seamlessly? And if so, can I assign numberOfLoop as in AVAudioplayer, instead of isLooping = true? Thanks for helping me exploring. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no numberOfLoop variable in AKPlayer. If you wanted to catch the completion event yourself, then you don't use buffering or isLooping - then you can get notified when it has finished and increment your own counter and restart the player. When a player is doing buffered looping there is no internal callback that a loop has cycled.

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer! I can add "player.loop.start / player.loop.end" on preparePlayer() function, so I can assign the region I want to repeat. I didn't have to put parameters on player.play(from: to:). Here :

```
func preparePlayer() {

    player.isLooping = true
    player.buffering = .always
    player.loop.start = 0
    player.loop.end = 7.5

    }

func startPlayer() {    

    let startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
    player.play(at: startTime)

    }
```

That's it! Looks like I have to set player.buffering as .always instead of .dynamics so loop goes seamlessly. But I still want to know how to set the number of repeat. I guess numberOfLoop function doesn't work on AKPlayer..? Thank you very much.